# TypeScript generic type predicate

Tags: typescript

How do you write a generic type predicate in TypeScript?

In the following example, `if (shape.kind == 'circle')` doesn't narrow the type to `Shape<'circle'>`/`Circle`/`{ kind: 'circle', radius: number }`

```
interface Circle {
  kind: 'circle';
  radius: number;
}

interface Square {
  kind: 'square';
  size: number;
}

type Shape<T = string> = T extends 'circle' | 'square'
  ? Extract<Circle | Square, { kind: T }>
  : { kind: T };

declare const shape: Shape;
if (shape.kind == 'circle') shape.radius;
// error TS2339: Property 'radius' does not exist on type '{ kind: string; }'.
```

I tried writing a generic type predicate to work around this, but the following doesn't work because [the type parameter isn't available at runtime](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-cant-i-write-typeof-t-new-t-or-instanceof-t-in-my-generic-function)

```
function isShape1<T extends string>(shape: Shape): shape is Shape<T> {
  return shape.kind extends T;
}
```

The following does work, but only if the type parameter `T` is a literal (has the same value at compile- and runtime)

```
function isShape2<T extends string>(shape: Shape, kind: T): shape is Shape<T> {
  return shape.kind == kind;
}

if (isShape2(shape, 'circle')) shape.radius; // Works ✓

declare const kind: string;
if (!isShape2(shape, kind)) shape.kind;
// error TS2339: Property 'kind' does not exist on type 'never'.
```

### Update 1

@jcalz The trouble is I need

```
declare const kind: string;
if (kind != 'circle' && kind != 'square') shape = { kind };
```

to work. I'd like to use a discriminated union, but can't, as you point out. If it were a discriminated union, could you write a generic type predicate?

```
type Shape<T = string> = Extract<Circle | Square, { kind: T }>;
```

The following still only works if the type parameter is a literal

```
function isShape3<T extends Shape['kind']>(shape: Shape, kind: T): shape is Shape<T> {
  return shape.kind == kind;
}

if (isShape3(shape, 'circle')) shape.radius; // Works ✓

declare const kind: Shape['kind']; // 'circle' | 'square'
if (!isShape3(shape, kind)) shape.kind;
// error TS2339: Property 'kind' does not exist on type 'never'.
```

The only difference is in this case the compiler already provides a working type predicate

```
if (shape.kind != kind) shape.kind; // Works ✓
```

### Update 2

@jcalz At runtime could it for example do the same thing as `shape.kind == kind`?

Here's a more concise demo

```
declare const s: string;
declare const kind: 'circle' | 'square';
declare let shape: 'circle' | 'square';

if (s == kind) shape = s; // Works ✓
if (shape != kind) shape.length; // Works ✓

function isShape1(s: string, kind: 'circle' | 'square') {
  return s == kind;
}

if (isShape1(s, kind)) shape = s;
// error TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"square" | "circle"'.
// https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16069

function isShape2(
  s: string,
  kind: 'circle' | 'square'
): s is 'circle' | 'square' {
  return s == kind;
}

if (isShape2(s, kind)) shape = s; // Works ✓
if (!isShape2(shape, kind)) shape.length;
// error TS2339: Property 'length' does not exist on type 'never'.
```

### Update 3

Thanks @jcalz and @KRyan for your thoughtful answers! @jcalz's solution is promising, especially if I disallow the non-narrowing case, vs. merely disarming it (via overload).

However it's still subject to the [problem you point out](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11670#issuecomment-261115991) (Number.isInteger(), bad things happen). Consider the following example

```
function isTriangle<
  T,
  K extends T extends K ? never : 'equilateral' | 'isosceles' | 'scalene'
>(triangle: T, kind: K): triangle is K & T {
  return triangle == kind;
}

declare const triangle: 'equilateral' | 'isosceles' | 'scalene';
declare const kind: 'equilateral' | 'isosceles';

if (!isTriangle(triangle, kind)) {
  switch (triangle) {
    case 'equilateral':
    // error TS2678: Type '"equilateral"' is not comparable to type '"scalene"'.
  }
}
```

`triangle` will never be narrower than `kind` so `!isTriangle(triangle, kind)` will never be `never`, thanks to the conditional type () however it remains narrower than it should be (unless `K` is a literal).

### Update 4

Thanks again @jcalz and @KRyan for patiently explaining how this can in fact be accomplished, and the consequent weaknesses. I've chosen @KRyan's answer for contributing the fake-nominal idea, though your combined answers are extremely helpful!

My takeaway is that the type of `s == kind` (or `triangle == kind` or `shape.kind == kind`) is built in and not (yet) available to users, to assign to other things (like predicates).

I'm not sure that's exactly the same as [one-sided type guards](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15048) b/c the false branch of `s == kind` does narrow in (one) case

```
declare const triangle: 'equilateral' | 'isosceles' | 'scalene';
if (triangle != 'scalene')
  const isosceles: 'equilateral' | 'isosceles' = triangle;
```

And to better motivate this question in the first place

1. I have a type which is almost a discriminated union (DNS RRs) except I can't enumerate all of the discriminant's values (in general it's a `string | number`, extensions are permitted). Consequently the built-in `rr.rdtype == 'RRSIG'` behavior doesn't apply. Unless I first narrow it to a true discriminated union with a user-defined type guard (`isTypedRR(rr) && rr.rdtype == 'RRSIG'`), which isn't a terrible option.
2. I can implement user-defined type guards for each RR type I can enumerate, but that's a lot of repetition (`function isRRSIG(rr): rr is RR<'RRSIG'>`, `function isDNSKEY(rr): rr is RR<'DNSKEY'>`, etc.). Probably this is what I'll continue to do: It's repetitious but obvious.
3. The trouble with a trivial generic type guard is that non-literals aren't disallowed but don't make sense (unlike `s == kind`/`rr.rdtype == rdtype`). e.g. `function isRR<T>(rr, rdtype: T): rr is RR<T>`. Hence this question.

This prevents me from say wrapping `isTypedRR(rr) && rr.rdtype == rdtype` in `function isRR(rr, rdtype)`. Inside the predicate `rr` is narrowed rationally, but outside the only option is (currently) `rr is RR<T>` (or now a fake-nominal).

Maybe when [type guards are inferred](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16069), it'll be trivial to rationally narrow the type outside the predicate as well? Or when [types can be negated](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29317), it'll be possible to make a true discriminated union given a non-enumerable discriminant. I do wish the type of `s == kind` were (more conveniently :-P) available to users. Thanks again!

Comment: I think your `Shape` type is the issue, not the type guard... maybe you want `type Shape<T extends (Circle | Square)["kind"] = (Circle | Square)["kind"]> = Extract<Circle | Square, { kind: T }>;`... or maybe you should just have `type Shape = Circle | Square` and something like `type ShapeKind<T extends Shape["kind"]> = Extract<Shape, {kind: T}>` and not try to use a single type name for both things.   
`

Comment: Also, [discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions) only work if they have a discriminant property where each member of the union can be distinguished at compile time.  The type `{kind: string}` doesn't count as a discriminated union, or even as a union, so it's not going to behave nicely.  Checking `{kind: string}` against another `{kind: string}` with a type guard is only going to leave it unchanged (in the "true" case) or narrow it to `never` (in the "false" case), as your code shows.

Comment: @-mentions in the body of your question don't alert anyone; I just happened to stumble along your update.  So, yes, the `kind` parameter in the user-defined type guard should be of a single string literal.  I don't understand what you mean by "generic type guard" here; what, at runtime, do you expect to happen with `if (!isShape(obj, kind)) { ... }` when `kind` is of a type wider than a string literal (e.g., if it is `"Circle" | "Square"` or `string`)?   I guess I am not sure what the use case is.   Can you explain what you want the type guard to be doing *at runtime*?

Comment: @jcalz Update 2

Comment:  User-defined type guards don't work the same as `==` in the false case (or as `!=` in the true case).  If the guard `(x: T) => x is U` returns `false`, the type of `x` will be narrowed to `Exclude<T, U>`, whereas when `x == y` returns `false`, no narrowing of `x` or `y` happens at all.  If it is not appropriate to narrow on failure, don't use a user-defined type guard (or [bad things happen](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11670#issuecomment-261115991)). If `T` and `U` are the same type (e.g., `"square" | "circle"`), such narrowing results in `never`, which is bad.

Comment: Or, without [one-sided user defined type guards](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15048), I can't come up with something that acts the way you want.  And I don't know if we'll ever get those.

Comment: @KRyan, I said "if". *If* it is not appropriate to narrow on failure, *then* you should not use a user-defined type guard. See the [example](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11670#issuecomment-261115991) where TypeScript was treating `Number.isInteger(x)` as a user-defined type guard returning `x is number`. This was fine for testing values like `0` (true implies `0` is a number) and `""` (false implies `""` is not a number), but really bad for testing values like `0.5` (false implies `0.5` is not a number?!). User-defined type guards are great, but not always appropriate.

Comment: @jcalz So you did, my bad. I was surprised to see such an expert in TS say that, should have triple-checked I was reading correctly.

Comment: I am very confused why you need type-narrowing to happen when you don’t know what type you’re trying to narrow to.

Comment: @jcalz Update 3

Comment: Ugh, I see... I might have to completely rewrite (or delete) my answer.  An equality test against any non-unit value simply can't be used as a user-defined type guard.  A one-sided type guard is a possibility, but I feel like maybe @KRyan should answer that since it's [his idea](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15048#issuecomment-534376266).

Comment: Updated my answer for probably the final time.

Comment: Yeah, I updated mine too, but... this shouldn’t be one question. Questions shouldn’t really be “updated” at all. It’s getting very difficult to follow, and very difficult to understand what it is you’re really trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### About narrowing conditional types

So fundamentally, your problem here is that narrowing a value does not narrow its type for the sake of mapped or conditional types. See [this issue on the GitHub bug tracker](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21879), and specifically [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21879#issuecomment-373280444) explaining why this does not work:

> If I've read correctly, I think this is working as intended; in the general case, the type of `foobar` itself doesn't necessarily reflect that `FooBar` (the type variable) will describe identical types of a given instantiation. For example:
>
> ```
> function compare<T>(x: T, y: T) {
>   if (typeof x === "string") {
>     y.toLowerCase() // appropriately errors; 'y' isn't suddenly also a 'string'
>   }
>   // ...
> }
>
> // why not?
> compare<string | number>("hello", 100);
> ```

Using type-guards can get you part of the way there:

```
interface Circle {
    kind: 'circle';
    radius: number;
}

interface Square {
    kind: 'square';
    size: number;
}

type Shape<T = string> = T extends 'circle' | 'square'
    ? Extract<Circle | Square, { kind: T }>
    : { kind: T };

declare const s: string;
declare let shape: Shape;

declare function isShapeOfKind<Kind extends string>(
    shape: Shape,
    kind: Kind,
): shape is Shape<Kind>;

if (s === 'circle' && isShapeOfKind(shape, s)) {
    shape.radius;
}
else if (s === 'square' && isShapeOfKind(shape, s)) {
    shape.size;
}
else {
    shape.kind;
}
```

But you have to check the type of `s` before you can use `isShapeOfKind` and expect it to work. That’s because prior to checking `s === 'circle'` or `s === 'square'`, the type of `s` is `string`, so the inference you get `isShapeOfKind<string>(shape, s)` and that only tells us that `shape is Shape<string>` which we already knew (and the false case is `never` because `shape` is defined to be a `Shape`, that is, a `Shape<string>`—it will never not be one). What you’d like to happen (but what Typescript doesn’t do) is for it to instead be something like `Shape<typeof s>` and then as more information about `s` is determined, knowledge about `shape` is determined. Typescript doesn’t track types of separate variables that may be related to one another.

The other way you could do this is to make things not a separate variable, if you really had to. That is, define a couple of interfaces like

```
interface ShapeMatchingKind<Kind extends string> {
    shape: Shape<Kind>;
    kind: Kind;
}

interface ShapeMismatchesKind<ShapeKind extends string, Kind extends string> {
    shape: Shape<ShapeKind>;
    kind: Kind;
}

type ShapeAndKind = ShapeMatchingKind<string> | ShapeMismatchesKind<string, string>;

declare function isShapeOfKind(
    shapeAndKind: ShapeAndKind,
): shapeAndKind is ShapeMatchingKind<string>;

const shapeAndKind = { shape, kind: s };
if (isShapeOfKind(shapeAndKind)) {
    const pretend = shapeAndKind as ShapeMatchingKind<'circle'> | ShapeMatchingKind<'square'>;
    switch (pretend.kind) {
        case 'circle':
            pretend.shape.radius;
            break;
        case 'square':
            pretend.shape.size;
            break;
        default:
            shapeAndKind.shape.kind;
            break;
    }
}
```

Even here, though, you have to use the `pretend` trick—a version of the variable cast to a narrower type, and then when `pretend` is `never`, you know the original variable in fact *wasn’t* part of that narrower type. Further, the narrower type has to be `ShapeMatchesKind<A> | ShapeMatchesKind<B> | ShapeMatchesKind<C>` rather than `ShapeMatchesKind<A | B | C>` because a `ShapeMatchesKind<A | B | C>` could have `shape: Shape<A>` and `kind: C`. (If you have a union `A | B | C`, you can achieve the distributed version you need using a conditional type, though.)

In our code we combine `pretend` often with `otherwise`:

```
function otherwise<R>(_pretend: never, value: R): R {
    return value;
}
```

The advantage of `otherwise` is that you can write your `default` case like this:

```
default:
    otherwise(pretend, shapeAndKind.shape.kind);
    break;
```

Now `otherwise` will demand that `pretend` is `never`—making sure your switch statement covered all the possibilities in `pretend`’s narrowed type. This is useful if you ever add a new shape that you want to handle specifically.

You don’t have to use `switch` here, obviously; a chain of `if`/`else if`/`else` will work just the same way.

#### About imperfect typeguards

In your final iteration, your problem is that `isTriangle` returns `false` to `typeof triangle & typeof kind` when really what is `false` is that the *value* of `triangle` and the *value* of `kind` do not match. So you get a situation where Typescript sees both `'equilateral'` and `'isosceles'` as ruled out, because `typeof kind` was `'equilateral' | 'isosceles'` but `kind`’s actual value was only one of those two things.

You can get around this with [fake nominal types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#can-i-make-a-type-alias-nominal), so you can do something like

```
class MatchesKind { private 'matches some kind variable': true; }

declare function isTriangle<T, K>(triangle: T, kind: K): triangle is T & K & MatchesKind;

declare const triangle: 'equilateral' | 'isosceles' | 'scalene';
declare const kind: 'equilateral' | 'isosceles';

if (!isTriangle(triangle, kind)) {
    switch (triangle) {
        case 'equilateral': 'OK';
    }
}
else {
    if (triangle === 'scalene') {
//      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//      This condition will always return 'false' since the types
//      '("equilateral" & MatchesKind) | ("isosceles" & MatchesKind)'
//      and '"scalene"' have no overlap.
        'error';
    }
}
```

Note that I used `if` here—`switch` doesn’t seem to work for some reason, it allows `case 'scalene'` in the second block with no complaints even though the type of `triangle` at that point should make that impossible.

**However**, this seems like a really, really bad design. It might just be the hypothetical illustration scenario, but I am really struggling to determine why you would want to design things this way. It’s not at all clear why you would want to check `triangle` against the value of `kind` and have the result appear in the type domain, but without narrowing `kind` to the point that you can actually know its type (and thus `triangle`’s). It would be better to narrow `kind` first, and then use it to narrow `triangle`—in that situation, you have no problems. You seem to be reversing some logic somewhere, and Typescript is—reasonably, I think—uncomfortable with that. I certainly am.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to address your "update 2" code, but the suggestion should apply to the general issue.  I think the main situation here is that `isShape(s, k)` should only act as a type guard on `s` if `s` isn't already a narrower type than `k` is.  Otherwise you don't want `isShape(s, k)` to do *anything* to the type of `s`, since in neither the `true` or the `false` case is anything of relevance implied (or at least nothing that can be represented in the type system).

Therefore my suggestion is to [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) the function so that it is only a user-defined type guard in the "right" situations, like this:

```
type Kind = "circle" | "square";

// isShape(s, k) should only act as a type guard if s is not of a narrower type than k
function isShape<K extends Kind, S extends [S] extends [K] ? never : string>(
  s: S,
  kind: K
): s is S & K;
// otherwise, isShape(s, k) is not a type guard but just a boolean test
function isShape(s: string, kind: Kind): boolean;
function isShape(s: string, kind: Kind): boolean {
  return s === kind;
}
```

That first overload signature works because `S` is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) to the [conditional type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#conditional-types) `[S] extends [K] ? : never : string`.  If `S` is inferred by the value of `s` to be same or narrower type as that of `kind`, then the constraint becomes `S extends never`, which will generally fail, and the compiler will try the next overload signature (which will succeed).  Otherwise, if `S` is inferred by the value of `s` to be a wider or different type, the constraint becomes `S extends string` and the inference will succeed (assuming `S` is assignable to `string`) and the function will act as a type guard.

Now let's see how it behaves:

```
declare const s: string;
declare const kind: Kind;
declare let shape: Kind;

// Use of type guard on string against Kind literal:
if (isShape(s, "circle")) {
  const x: "circle" = s; // s is "circle"
} else {
  const x: typeof s = "someString"; // s is string
}

// Use of type guard on Kind against Kind literal:
if (isShape(shape, "circle")) {
  const x: "circle" = shape; // shape is "circle"
} else {
  const x: "square" = shape; // shape is "square"
}

// Use of type guard on string against Kind:
if (isShape(s, kind)) {
  const x: Kind = s; // s is Kind
} else {
  const x: typeof s = "someString"; // s is string
}

// Use of type guard on Kind against Kind:
if (isShape(shape, kind)) {
  const x: Kind = shape; // shape is Kind (no narrowing has taken place)
} else {
  const x: Kind = shape; // shape is Kind (no narrowing has taken place)
}
```

I think that covers all your use cases.  Does that work?

It would be simpler, though, if you just don't use `isShape(s, k)` when you already know that `s` is of a narrower type than `k`.  When you use user-defined type guards for a test where there are likely false negatives (where the `false` return does not imply anything new about the type of the guarded parameter), you are shooting yourself in the foot.  The above overload definition tries to make `isShape()` disarm itself when you point it at your foot, but it's just easier for all involved not to require such things. You could use `isShape(s, k)` when `s` is wider than `k`, and otherwise just use `s === k` or some other non-type-guard test.

But in any case, I hope this helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#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-9oARbTdOKXBSjBZ0jLiUzzMsiIbN7IA)

---

#### UPDATE

You've expanded `Kind` to three literals, and I see now that my thoughts about which situations are the "right" ones to narrow were not completely correct. Now my plan of attack is for `isTriangle(t, k)` is that it should be a regular type guard *only* when `k` is a single string literal type and not a union at all.  This is detectable by the type system, but it's not pretty:

```
type _NotAUnion<T, U> = T extends any
  ? [U] extends [T] ? unknown : never
  : never;

type IsSingleStringLiteral<
  T extends string,
  Y = T,
  N = never
> = string extends T ? N : unknown extends _NotAUnion<T, T> ? Y : N;
```

If `k` is a union of types, then you should only narrow in the `true` case and not in the `false` case.  This is a [one-sided user-defined type guard](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15048), which doesn't officially exist in TypeScript.  However, @KRyan [notes](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15048#issuecomment-534376266) that you can emulate a one-sided type guard by making the guarded type narrow to a [nominal or nominal-like type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#can-i-make-a-type-alias-nominal).  I'll use branding, like `type BrandedFoo = Foo & {__brand: "Foo"}`... where I don't expect the `__brand` property to actually exist at runtime, but the compiler thinks it's there, and can use it to distinguish `Foo` from `BrandedFoo`. If the type guard narrows from `Foo` to `BrandedFoo` on the true case, then in the false case it will remain `Foo` because `Exclude<Foo, BrandedFoo>` is just `Foo`.

I'm still using overloads to determine which type of type guard we want, based on the type of `kind`:

```
type TriangleKind = "equilateral" | "isosceles" | "scalene";

function isTriangle<K extends IsSingleStringLiteral<K, TriangleKind, never>>(
  triangle: string,
  kind: K
): triangle is K;
function isTriangle<K extends TriangleKind>(
  triangle: string,
  kind: K
): triangle is K & { __brand: K };
function isTriangle(triangle: string, kind: TriangleKind): boolean {
  return triangle == kind;
}
```

And let's take it through its paces:

```
declare const triangle: "equilateral" | "isosceles" | "scalene";
declare const twoKind: "equilateral" | "isosceles";
declare const allKind: "equilateral" | "isosceles" | "scalene";
declare const s: string;

// Use of type guard on string against TriangleKind literal:
if (isTriangle(s, "equilateral")) {
  const x: "equilateral" = s; // s is "equilateral"
} else {
  const x: typeof s = "someString"; // s is string
}

// Use of type guard on string against union of two TriangleKind types:
if (isTriangle(s, twoKind)) {
  const x: "equilateral" | "isosceles" = s; // s is "equilateral" | "isosceles"
} else {
  const x: typeof s = "someString"; // s is still string, no narrowing
}

// Use of type guard on string against TriangleKind:
if (isTriangle(s, allKind)) {
  const x: TriangleKind = s; // s is TriangleKind
} else {
  const x: typeof s = "someString"; // s is still string, no narrowing
}

// Use of type guard on TriangleKind against TriangleKind literal:
if (isTriangle(triangle, "equilateral")) {
  const x: "equilateral" = triangle; // triangle is "equilateral"
} else {
  const x: "isosceles" | "scalene" = triangle; // triangle is "isosceles" | "scalene"
}

// Use of type guard on TriangleKind against union of two TriangleKind types:
if (isTriangle(triangle, twoKind)) {
  const x: "equilateral" | "isosceles" = triangle; // triangle is "equilateral" | "isosceles"
} else {
  const x: typeof triangle = allKind; // triangle is still TriangleKind, no narrowing
}

// Use of type guard on TriangleKind against TriangleKind:
if (isTriangle(triangle, allKind)) {
  const x: TriangleKind = triangle; // triangle is TriangleKind
} else {
  const x: typeof triangle = allKind; // triangle is still TriangleKind, no narrowing
}
```

This all looks mostly right.  Note that in several of the true branches the type of the narrowed thing is branded, so you get `("isosceles" & {__brand: "isosceles"}) | ("scalene" & {__brand: "scalene"})` instead of `"isosceles" | "scalene"`.  You can mostly ignore those brands, but they are kind of ugly.

So there you go.  Complicated and messy, best I've got.

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/C4TwDgpgBA+gcge2AQQKoDsCWD0B4AqANFKgHxQC8U+UEAHsBOgCYDOUAhuiAFBRQB+KAG1UAXVoMmbEfglCArugDW6BAHd0UAFxR0EAG4QATnx17DJgNw8eoSFACSrAMqZ0AcwA2EF8GPuHgAymIzGHF64ZjT0jCzsrP6BhGYAmpTUKfxwGfpGpuRUiQGeknEyNEI5ukqqGlqx0uzwSGhYOATE+ORC6bpwNnbg0PgBXN4QANLuzBkARBAAjgqYXhxhEXNQAD5Qc5isCKwAxhA+rFu7cycRTBBzgwBmSsfA2FoHo5jjPriTZU0nK5Aj4-CVgqETBE-l0xp4fNMWMQ8iZSKQABRmJI-CC6YrJMzKGa6SY8ACUumx8OgBygkxsz3Qr3eUE+cImfwB8Wo7IRMwxWN5uKg+M8WSgRJYJPJlKFrPY-wAZFAAN6wGAAI3CUrpUAAvgyXm8cPKvjj0VSJnikmKJcSed9qYjmBSoBqEAgfFxVWZjBBgApjFpLT5KFRJcwbHrbMwIMc1n6oMccIkoCHhQtlqt1lCvJc9gcjqdzvnrsdbvoHjxY-GOInk+hU8B1AhnbpMys1hs8zsC4cTmcIBcbDWE9AG6mIl423slp2c+Ee1dCwOS72yxX7iO42OkyngCLreDBgB6E8kVjQBCPNPDKAeBR12Ym0UeTgeDjuVNmp0zKBeSFF20HhMBvdE2UdCZ0VYYgO2zbs5jJMkfX4CcDzods53g3MtiKKwoDPEV5VnLMuxwng9VoLxLxQvdG3QylhmvIiqGuBAAFtfBtDwHgI892FpV8KNsQjUBo5j7GgB8nygF9uPfT96KgJQWQklsHRxZ1b0gVhgNAqBwNYH8oJgtMW2dJDaLQqAMJI+cEPXFdiyHXCRXwwiBPYOCyMXUsnMHC4KKomiVTMazbMk5j2FYw5OLBQJeI84jElWLwRW45EED0OtjA0QJhJ4UTxJvST70fYxny0V8FK-A9jL5KUQLAiDzVMqcLOQ0LUP3GzdHqqY-zwviiNpfrnSCs4QrCnqIqYm9or2WKuPBRL+OSt4vDS19Muy4xcvUfLo0K88xKvEq72kirZK0Ma-w4D9ao038WH-QCIj05qjKFC0hVgrCfM2Syuro1NbO8hdNgydN3PPdNiPBhCJuo6BgfC9t-LXK4bh8SsoaFGG0zlWl9n7ZyLnXbG7jmAqirO7SpPKyqnomLT7sU1MVJNNSstul7JN0pqDJa6kfsgnxiGbVsZiB6alLB-6IaXPsiwC1zoeGuHiYVhzl1J1Wkam7q5cYyAJLlKh2pmAnNYSDa0t55gdvQHK8s8GmTuK+mypkk0HZqpSHY+oWvrFiBRZxYhLZYGWjdBvqhS0qh1cIm3mYa5gDZR2W4-ps3Q4yKPIw1onbdStOBqRPQsudvbXY8YSgA)

Good luck again!

Comment: I wonder if habitually using `isShape(s, k) && isShape(k, s)` gets the right results consistently without the overload. Obnoxious redundancy and runtime overhead, so not a great solution, but it might be less error-prone.