# Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T[K]'

Tags: typescript

I get an error when trying to assign a string value to 'value', even though I check that 'value' is a string before doing so, and still get an error. Maybe I did something wrong?

```
function updateTable<T extends Record<string, unknown>, K extends keyof T>(object: T, key: K, value: T[K]) {
  if (typeof value === "string") value = `'${value}'`; // error here

  return [object, key, value];
}
```

Error: **Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T[K]'.**

Comment: Does it need to be of type `T[K]`? Technically your Record uses a type of `unknown` so shouldn't your value also use the same type? To simplify, isn't this function just: `function updateTable(object: Record<string, unknown>, key: string, value: unknown)`?

Comment: If value is already string, why do you use string interpolation here?
You just trying to convert string value to string

Comment: @captain-yossarian this is necessary, the string must remain a string, but inside quotation marks.

Comment: @PhilB. Technically, yes, but this is until a object is passed to the first argument, then the string or number will replace unknown, otherwise the if block will not work, so I don't see any reason for an error.

Comment: Might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57750277/typescript-generic-type-predicate

Comment: @Wondermarin, `T[K]` is "an indexed access type or lookup type. It represents the type of the property K of the type T" (see https://mariusschulz.com/blog/keyof-and-lookup-types-in-typescript#indexed-access-types) so I believe `string` is too generic to be assigned as technically `T[K]` is specifically the value of the lookup, not just the value type of the object.

Comment: @PhilB. ok, do you have any ideas how to avoid the error?

Comment: The only solution I could find: [user defined type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types).